# Get jsonvalue without a name

Tags: java, android, json

i'm struggling with a JSONObject. I allready returned some json and converted it succesfully to objects and list of objects. My now i'm stuck.

This is the JSONObject i'm getting:

```
{"Result":true,"Messages":["Goe bezig!"]}
```

I'm able to get the Messages, but i can't seem to get the boolean in Result. Can somebody explain how to get it plz?

Here is the code:

```
public boolean Convert(JSONObject json) {
    try 
    {
        return json.getBoolean("Result");
    } 
    catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @BjornVdkerckhove : *but i can't seem to get the boolean in Result* mean? your are getting any error then post your log with question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked fine for me, although it's pretty vague your question.

```
    String jsonString = "{\"Result\":true,\"Messages\":[\"Goe bezig!\"]}";

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

    boolean result = (Boolean) jsonObject.get("Result");

    System.out.println(result);
```

You might want to catch at the end of your method `Exception` as well:

```
try {
   return json.getBoolean("Result");
} catch (JSONException e) {
   e.printStackTrace(); // replace these with `Log` statement

   return false;
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace(); // replace these with `Log` statement

   return false;
}
```